# Accessing EOS transactions

Tags: keosd

I have a very beginners question. 
I was following the online tutorial for deploying a 'hello' contract between alice and bob. [Link](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/setting-up-your-environment)

I got everything working, but I was wondering if there is a way that I can see the transaction online? Like see the details of the transaction. I want to have access to it from different places, is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use the eosq.app to query the transactions or some full node to see the transaction and its traces

Answer (score 0):

In this tutorial, your transaction is gonna happen on your own test blockchain, so you gonna be able to see it on your local blockchain but not on the official blockchain mainnet

If you want to see your transaction online I advise you to try on a testnet, you can try with this link [How to deploy a contract to testnet?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/how-to-deploy-a-contract-to-testnet)